# Cannot register the component in castle windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I have used the below link for the castle windsor dependency injection.I am not able to register the component.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1052382/ASP-NET-MVC-Dependency-Injection-using-Windsor#_comments

```
public class ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container,
                        Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<Interfaces.TestInterface>()
                     .ImplementedBy<Services.TestServices>()
                     .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

ErrorMessage:

> An exception of type
>   'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException' occurred in
>   Castle.Windsor.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Component
>   TestForCastleWindsor.Services.TestServices could not be registered.
>   There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify
>   the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique
>   name.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't registered the component already somewhere else? You don't have any customisation on the registration pipeline anywhere?

Comment: I have not registered the component elsewhere

Comment: public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Classes.
                    FromThisAssembly().
                    BasedOn<IController>().
                    If(c => c.Name.EndsWith("Controller")).
                    LifestyleTransient());

           

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(container));
        }
    }

Comment: Just before the registration line, put a breakpoint on, you can inspect the container and it has a list of registered services and their associated implementations

Answer (score 0):

That component is being registered twice. This can happen when IWindsorInstaller implementations or components are picked up by convention. For example, all assemblies in a directory are scanned for implementations of IWindsorInstaller and an old duplicate assembly is present. Or all implementations of another interface also implemented by your component are previously registered.